# upscale but keep pixilation

Tags: vector, resize, raster, pixel-art

**I want to keep the quality of my image low!** I'm asking here because all my searches have answered the opposite of my question. To simplify: I've drawn a 60-something x 60-something pixel circle in Photoshop using the polygon tool and applied an outer glow effect. I'd like to upscale this by a large amount (800% - 1000%) but KEEP that pixilation. When I upscale the rest of my pixel art, it comes out perfect (I researched the proper way to upscale pixel art!), but the circle drawn by photoshop smooths out.

Is there any way to make my image larger without forcing it to smooth out? To my understanding, if the circle drawn has been rasterized, shouldn't it maintain all its rough edges? I have the Image Interpolation setting set to Nearest Neighbor.

The first image is what I'd like to see at a higher resolution.

The second image is unfortunately what I'm getting.

EDIT: I answered my own question! Simply flattening the image did exactly what I wanted.

[image: nice and pixilated :D]
[image: too smooth!! D:]

Comment: Welcome gideonzane. You can answer your own question by providing the answer in the answer box, and (possibly after a short time) you can accept that answer as well. Doing that helps other people find answers easily.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What software are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the "**Nearest neighbor**" method, present on many programs.

This will duplicate the rows and columns.

Try to think in multiples, for example 60px x 10 = 600px. Or multiplied by 20 will give you 1200px.

If you do not choose exact multiples some rows will have let's say 11 "clones" and some will have 10, making the resampled pixels uneven.

By "exact" I do not mean 10x numbers, you can multiply by 19 instead of 20, giving you 1140px, but do not use 1141px.